# Prevent javascript sdk from storing cognito id token on localstorage?

Tags: angular, local-storage, amazon-cognito

I have a SPA with angular where I'm using AWS cognito along with the javascript aws sdk 'amazon-cognito-identity-js' to authenticate my users.

The problem is that the tokens are stored by the sdk on localstorage. So after I do a globalSignOut, the access token is invalidated, but the id token is not revoked and
continues to be valid until the expiry time is over (witch is 1h by default)
If a hacker retrieves my id token while I'm connected, he can still use it after signingOut to connect to the backend.

So, my question is there any method how to prevent the sdk to store all the tokens on localstorage? especially the idtoken?
do you have any suggestions? or did your encounter this beahviour before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any answer here please

Comment: Show your sample code will help to resolve. But I never has experienced aws cognito storing the tokens to local storage automatically. But if you generate a client credential from browser, it will store a credentials cache, we have to call AWS.config.credentials.clearCachedId() once logged out from the apps.